# how to make compound index for multiple column range queries

Tags: mongodb, indexing, range, nosql

I want to make a range query on multiple columns. for example:

db.dmnscore.find({price:{$lte:10}, "updated" : {"$gte" : new 
Date(1304874799000)} ,"score" : {"$gte" : 0,"$lte" : 
1000}).sort({score:-1}) 
Is it possible to make a proper compound index for this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to test it yourself. Create an index on the properties, then run this query:

```
db.dmnscore.find({price:{$lte:10}, "updated" : {"$gte" : new Date(1304874799000)} ,"score" : {"$gte" : 0,"$lte" : 1000}).sort({score:-1}).explain()
```

notice the `explain()` on the end. If the result contains `Btree` you're good, if the result contains `BasicCursor` it hasn't used the index.